# prepending to elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list that consists of events occurring on certain dates of certain months.  To simplify, the list looks like this:

```
list = {{"June","19","a"},{"b"},{"c"},{"August","2","d"},{"e"}}
```

I would like to prepend the month and date elements to each succeeding element until a new date is encountered, so as to make:

```
res = {{"June","19","a"},{"June","19","b"},{"June","19","c"},{"August","2","d"},{"August","2","e"}}
```

...and so forth.  I'd like to avoid DateObjects and just work with strings.

I would like to generalize the question, by allowing the list to contain variable numbers of elements following the month/day elements:

```
list = {{"June","19","a","a1"},{"b","b2","b3","b4"},{"c"},{"August","2","d"},{"e","e1}} to give:


res = {{"June","19","a","a1"},{"June","19","b","b2","b3","b4"},{"June","19","c"},{"August","2","d"},{"August","2","e","e1}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SequenceReplace[
  list,
  {{m_, d_, el_}, rest : {_} ...} :> 
   Sequence @@ Join[{{m, d, el}}, Join[{m, d}, #] & /@ {rest}]
  ]
```

> `{{"June", "19", "a"}, {"June", "19", "b"}, {"June", "19",    "c"},
>   {"August", "2", "d"}, {"August", "2", "e"}}`

For the modified list given in a comment below:

```
SequenceReplace[
 list,
 {{m_, d_, elems__}, rest : ({_} | {_, _}) ...} :> 
  Sequence @@ Join[{{m, d, elems}}, Join[{m, d}, #] & /@ {rest}]
 ]
```

And the most general version given can be solved like this:

```
months = Alternatives["January", "February", "Mars", "April", "May", 
   "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", 
   "December"];

SequenceReplace[
 list,
 {{m : months, d_, elems__}, rest : {Except[months], ___} ...} :> 
  Sequence @@ Join[{{m, d, elems}}, Join[{m, d}, #] & /@ {rest}]
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reponses Alan and C.E!  They work for the test list, but fail for the following minor modification:

Comment: @Suite401 What modification? Please add it to the question.

Comment: Sorry I ran afoul of the time limit for adding comments: List = {{"June","19","a","a1"},{"b","b1"},{"c"},{"August","2","d"},{"e"}}, where the elements following the date may be lists consisting of more than one member. In this case, the desired result would be: {{"June", "19", "a", "a1"}, {"June", "19", "b", "b1"}, {"June", "19", 
  "c"}, {"August", "2", "d"}, {"August", "2", "e"}}

Comment: @Suite401 Added a solution for that list to my answer.

Comment: Thanks yes this works.

Comment: with the following test data, {{"June", "19", "a", "a1"}, {"b", "b1"}, {"c", "c2", "c3", 
  "c1"}, {"August", "2", "d"}, {"e"}}C.E.'s solution gives: {{"June", "19", "a", "a1"}, {"June", "19", "b", "b1"}, {"c", "c2", 
  "c3", "c1"}, {"August", "2", "d"}, {"August", "2", "e"}}.

Comment: which  does not get the dates in front of each of the elements.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Suite401 Please don't post new versions of the list as a comment, update your question instead so that everybody can see it. And really, really make sure that you have sufficiently explained what kind of data you have. If you can't find an example that covers all your cases, then you at least have to describe what all the different cases that are supposed to be covered are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77876/discussion-between-suite401-and-c-e).

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {{"June", "19", "a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"August", "2", "d"}, {"e"}}
f[lst_] := With[{date = Most[lst[[1]]]},
  Prepend[Join[date, #] & /@ lst[[2 ;;]], First@lst]
  ]
f /@ Split[list, 1 == Length[#2] &]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Module[{m = Split[#, 
        Not[MemberQ[DateString[{2018, #}, "MonthName"] & /@ Range[12], #2[[1]]]] &]}, 
    m[[;; , 2 ;;]] = Flatten /@ Thread[{#, #2}, List, {2}] & @@@ 
       Thread[{m[[;; , 1, ;; 2]], m[[;; , 2 ;;]]}]; 
    Join @@ m] &;
```

Examples:

```
list1 = {{"June", "19", "a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"August", "2", "d"}, {"e"}};
list2 = {{"June", "19", "a", "a1"}, {"b", "b2", "b3", "b4"}, {"c"}, 
  {"August", "2", "d"}, {"e", "e1"}} ;

f /@ {list1, list2}
```

> {{{"June", "19", "a"}, {"June", "19", "b"}, {"June", "19", 
>          "c"}, {"August", "2", "d"}, {"August", "2", "e"}},
>   {{"June", "19",  "a", "a1"}, {"June", "19", "b", "b2", "b3", "b4"}, {"June", "19", 
>          "c"}, {"August", "2", "d"}, {"August", "2", "e", "e1"}}}